# Is it correct to start a sentence with the infinitive of a verb without the "to"?

Tags: grammar

The context is: "Yes, your card made me close my birth month with a flourish!   Receive it on the last day of April was perfect and very meaningful to me."

Is it correct to start the sentence "Receive it on the last day......" ?

Thanks!

Christina

Comment: No, it has to be either "To receive it" or "Receiving it".  Otherwise you have a verb phrase as your subject instead of a noun phrase, which doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Hellion. I instinctively read it as an _imperative_ not an infinitive, meaning this was hortatory ad-speak, and of course the sentence then crashed against "was perfect" and imploded.

Comment: If English is not your native language and you're still learning it, you might want to make use of our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Hellion Hmm, but "Receiving it" is a verb phrase functioning as Subject!

Comment: @Araucaria, "receiving it" is a gerund, which is a verb-functioning-as-a-noun.  ;-p

Answer (score 4):

In that context, no. It should be either a gerund ("Receiving it on the last day of April was perfect and very meaningful to me") or a to-infinitive (To receive it on the last day of April was perfect and very meaningful to me"). However, the gerund sounds much more natural; the infinitive sounds stiff and formal.

Typically, starting a sentence with the infinitive without *to* means the sentence is a command:

- Go ten miles down the road.
- Be strong for your mother.
- Take this card to your aunt.

Comment: Englsih is not my native language. I am Brazilian, so I speak Portuguese. However I love Englsih and I love to learn the language!!!
Your prompt response helped me a lot!!!! Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry! I mean English!

Comment: I’m not sure why this was downvoted. The only inaccuracy is the phrasing “starting a sentence with the infinitive without _to_ means the sentence is a command”, which mixes up form and function: imperatives and infinitives are _functions_, and they are distinct. What you really mean to say here is that starting a sentence with the _base form_ (aka _lookup form_ or _dictionary form_) of a verb means the verb is an imperative. And of course it may also mean that it’s a present tense form with something (typically a subject) left out: “Want some coffee?” — “Nah. Don’t like it. Prefer tea.”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Some of these feel like stealth conditionals: “Be here by nine and win a free doughnut!” => “Should you be here by nine, you will win a free doughnut”.  I don’t think either of those is much of an imperative. “Get it in 2 days for only $5 more” => “For only $5 more, you will get it in 2 days”

Comment: @tchrist True—function is further subdivided into various categories, ‘imperative’ being here the morphological function, and ‘conditional’ or ‘pseudo-conditional’ being the semantic (?) function.

Comment: I did say that it's _typically_ a command; there are certainly situations where it isn't.